# Cutting TIFF in QGIS 3.0.2 produces an empty Raster

Tags: raster, gdal, clip, qgis-3

I am currently trying to cut a georeferenced TIFF image by using a Polygon as cutting boundary.

Both are saved in **EPSG 25832**.

When running the algorithm from the **Raster - > Extract menu** it runs and creates an empty Raster file, throws an error:

`Error 1: cutline Transformation failed.`

Also, the output Raster is set to **EPSG 3044 instead of 25832**.

When I open this empty file in the Foto viewer on Windows, it's just white. When I try to colour the pixels with 0 value in QGIS nothing is there. When I zoom to extend focus is on the right Spot where the Raster should be (but I have to set the right EPSG before - obviously).

How can I manage that?

Comment: Can you share the extent of the layers, as stated in the metadata of the layers' properties?